# Is there a better way to avoid if/then/else?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, if-statement

### Background

We have a request object that contains information. That specific object has a field called `partnerId` which determines what we are going to do with the request.

A typical approach would be a gigantic if/then/else:

```
function processRequest( request ){
    if( request.partnerId === 1 ){
        //code here
    }else if( request.partnerId === 23 ){
        //code here
    }
    //and so on. This would be a **huge** if then else.
}
```

This approach has two main problems:

- This function would be huge. Huge functions are a code smell (explaining why next) but mainly they become very hard to read  and maintain very quickly.
- This function would do more than one thing. This is a problem. Good coding practices recommend that 1 function should do only 1 thing.

### Our solution

To bypass the previous problems, I challenged my co-worker to come up with a different solution, and he came up with a function that dynamically builds the name of the function we want to use and calls it. Sounds complicated but this code will clarify it:

```
const functionHolder = {
    const p1 = request => {
        //deals with request
    };

    const p23 = request => {
        //deals with request
    };

    return { p1, p23 }; 
};

const processRequest = request => {
    const partnerId = request.partnerId;
    const result = functionHolder[`p${partnerId}`](request);
    return result;
};
```

### Problems

This solution has advantages over the previous one:

1. There is no main function with an huge gigantic if then else.
2. Each execution path is not a single function that does one thing only

However it also has a few problems:

1. We are using an object `functionHolder` which is in reality useless. `p1` and `p23` don't share anything in common, we just use this object because we don't know how else we can build the function's name dynamically and call it.
2. There is no `else` case. If we get an incorrect parameter the code blows.
3. Out eslint with rule `non-used-vars` complains that `p1` and `p23` are not being used and we don't know how to fix it ( https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars ).

The last problem, gives us the impression that perhaps this solution is not so great. Perhaps this pattern to avoid an if then else has some evil to it that we are yet to find.

### Questions

1. Is there any other pattern we can use to avoid huge if then else statements ( or switch cases )?
2. Is there a way to get rid of the `functionHolder` object?
3. Should we change the pattern or fix the rule?

Looking forward to any feedback!

Comment: might try as well on `codereview.stackexchange.com`

Comment: Interesting question and factory patterns come to mind but I assume the answer is primarily opinion-based. IMHO `Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of the unused variables by never declaring them in the first place:

```
const functionHolder = {
    p1: request => {
        //deals with request
    },
    p23: request => {
        //deals with request
    };
};

const processRequest = request => {
    const partnerId = request.partnerId;
    const method = functionHolder[`p${partnerId}`]
    if(method)   // Is there a method for `partnerId`?
        return method(request);
    return null; // No method found. Return `null` or call your default handler here.
};
```

To answer your points:

1. Yeap, as shown above.
2. Not without some kind of object.
3. That's up to you. Whatever you prefer.

Comment: Update `method` with `method(request)` and `return null` with call of some default handler

Comment: @Flying: Can you explain that a little more? What's wrong with how I'm doing it now?

Comment: @Cerbrus your handler doesn't get `request` as argument and it doesn't match signatures of the functions inside `functionHolder`

Comment: Right, forgot to pass the `request`. That's fixed now. Any other issues?

Comment: @Cerbrus also original question contains information about requirement to have default handler (`else` statement), but your example contains simple `return null`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm not understanding the question properly, but why not an object to hold the methods?

```
const functionHolder = {
  1: function(request) {
    // do something
  },
  23: function(request) {
    // do something
  },
  _default: function(request) {
    // do something
  }
}

function processRequest(request) {
  (functionHolder[request.partnerId] || functionHolder._default)(request)
}
```

---

Explanation:

1. The object `functionHolder` contains each of the methods used to deal with a given request.
2. The keys of `functionHolder` (e.g. `1`) correspond *directly* to the values of `request.partnerId`, and the values of these members are the appropriate methods.
3. The function `processRequest` "selects" the appropriate method in `functionHolder` (i.e. `object[key]`), and calls this method with the request as the parameter (i.e. `method(parameter)`).
4. We also have a default method, under the key `_default`, if `request.partnerId` does not match any existing key. Given `a || b`; if `a` is "falsy", in this case `undefined` (because there is no corresponding member of the object), evaluate to `b`.

---

If you are concerned about making `functionHolder` "bloated", then you can separate each of the methods:

```
const p1 = request => {
  // do something
}

const p23 = request => {
  // do something
}

const _default = request => {
  // do something
}
```

And then combine them into a "summary" object of sorts.

```
const functionHolder = {
  1: p1,
  23: p23,
  _default: _default
}
```

`processRequest` remains the same as above.

This adds a lot of global variables though.

---

Another advantage is you can import / change / declare methods on the fly. e.g.

```
functionHolder[1] = p1b // where p1b is another request handler (function) for `request.partnerId` = 1
functionHolder[5] = p5 // where p5 is a request handler (function) that has not yet been declared for `request.partnerId` = 5
```

---

Combining the above, without having to declare many global variables while also being able to separate the declaration of each method:

```
const functionHolder = {}

functionHolder._default = request => {
  // do something
}

functionHolder[1] = request => {
  // do something
}

functionHolder[23] = request => {
  // do something
}
```

`processRequest` remains the same as above.

You just have to be sure that the methods are "loaded in" to `functionHolder` before you call `processRequest`.

Comment: This will crash for `partnerId`s that have no handler.